# Why does negation flip all high bits of a number expect for the least significant bit?

Tags: math, integers, bit-manipulation

In his blog post on [512 bit division](https://xn--2-umb.com/17/512-bit-division/), Remco Bloemen makes the following assertion:

> ... negation flips all high bits of a number up to but not including the least significant one

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the EVM uses the [two's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to store signed values.

By definition, negating a number in two's complement involves two steps:

1. Flip all bits.
2. Add 1 to the flipped value.

The 1 is added at the end, so the least significant bit remains unchanged (it goes back to its original value, in a roundabout way).